# Как выровнять текст в рамке?

Tags: css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Сделал рамку в форме круга. И заполненность этого круга - это статистика. Повернул таблицу (transform: rotate(-45.0deg);). Конечно же логично, что и текст при этом повернулся. Как выровнить текст?

CSS

```css
.skills h1 {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.skills__stats {
  max-width: 775px;
  color: #1cb88b;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.circle__stats {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.circle__1,
.circle__2,
.circle__3,
.circle__4 {
  width: 152px;
  height: 152px;
  border: 10px solid #1cb88b;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.circle__1 {
  border-top: #fff solid 10px;
  transform: rotate(-45.0deg);
}

.circle__2 {
  border: #fff solid 10px;
  border-top-color: #1cb88b;
}
```

```html
<section class="skills">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Our <br> skills</h1>
    <div class="skills__stats">
      <div class="circle__stats">
        <div class="circle__1">75</div>
        <div class="circle__2">25</div>
        <div class="circle__3">75</div>
        <div class="circle__4">50</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут два примера и один на SVG и второй на html css и заметьте что svg можно управлять

```css
.chart {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 20px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.chart p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <circle  cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="230" transform="rotate(-90 100 100)"/>
  <text x="80" y="105" style="fill: red; font-size: 20px; font-family: sans-serif;"> 45%</text>
</svg>

<div class="chart">
  <p> 45%</p>
</div>
```